# Full name regex in javascript that also accepts space

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex that matchs fullnames , i saw the below regex on SO:

```
^[a-z]([-']?[a-z]+)*( [a-z]([-']?[a-z]+)*)+$
```

But i also need to match names with a dot(.) , so the name "arun K." should return true with the regex.

currently `/^[a-zA-Z]+(([',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/g.test('hello k.')`

will `return false`.

Comment: Poor Günther.  Regex is a poor choice for this, names are not so trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^([a-zA-Z'-.]+ [a-zA-Z'-.]+)$`

This won't do names with Umlauts, which may effect some of the names that you are checking, neither will it work for any language that doesn't use latin characters, so you may be better off simply checking that there is a space between two words. However, this should do if you take those into account.

For some names, you'll encounter double barrelled surnames, hence the `-` and in other cases (such as "O'Connor") there are `'` characters.

[See it working here](https://regex101.com/r/0s8eQm/1)

**Edit**

Asking how to make the last name optional in the comments:

`^([a-zA-Z'-.]+(?: [a-zA-Z'-.]+)?)$`

This groups the space and the last name together, the `?` at the end of this non-capture group makes it optional.

[See it working here](https://regex101.com/r/0s8eQm/3)

Comment: sorry this is not part of the question , but show do i make the part after the firdt + optional

Answer (score 1):

just put . in [a-z]. So 2 and 4 [a-z] will be [a-z.]

Comment: The dot is optional

Comment: ^[a-z]([-']?[a-z.]+)*( [a-z]([-']?[a-z.]+)*)+$

Comment: try this . is optional